# Using Cowboy as HTTP webserver for Express JS

Tags: javascript, http, express, webserver, cowboy

I see many websites which use `Cowboy` as HTTP Web server and `Express JS` as Web application server. Their `Server` HTTP header is Cowboy and `X-Powered-By` HTTP header is `Express`.
For example : http://passportjs.org/

I want to know why they do this? Why they use `Cowboy` as HTTP Web server in front of `Express`? And also how can I use `Cowboy` as HTTP web server? How can I use both of them?

Answer (score 4):

I think these sites use Heroku service as app container. And Heroku use [cowboyku](https://github.com/heroku/cowboyku) as web proxy for all web app which would be Java, Ruby, Node.js or any other programing languages it supports.